# Not able to get Push notification using Pushplugin

Tags: javascript, cordova, asp.net-web-api, phonegap-pushplugin

I am using Telerik Icenium and I tried pushPlugin. It was working in my app with GCM, but now I changed from GCM to FCM. I am trying to use **pushPlugin v2.0.0-rc2** and I am getting the error below:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined Uncaught TypeError:
>   PushNotification.init is not a function.

Below is the plugin I used.
https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push

Any suggestion on this would help me.